# Facebook style menu for iOS, on table cell click in menu, go to view with nib name

Tags: objective-c

i'm making a Facebook style menu for iOS, on table cell click in menu, go to view with nib name...

I have achieved this up to a point where i need to create a new view with a nib name "ListingsViewController". I have this code, but this is obviously replacing the menu view, when you slide it open, rather than the actual window view. When a cell is clicked, the men u should close and open the new view, but instead the menu closes, and when you reopen the menu, the listings view is in the menu view, not the actual main view when the menu is shut.

```
[self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1.- Instantiate your new controller

```
YouController *section = [YourController alloc] initwith....
```

2.- In "self" use:

```
[self addChildViewController:section];
[self.view addSubview:section.view];
```

3.- Adjust the frame to your needs

This works for me, but maybe you are using a different way to get the menu.

Comment: This works, but changes the menu view, but not my main view, the menu is a view, and i want to change the view from the menu controller, if this makes sense?

Comment: But you change the frame? cause you are only adding a subview, not changeing the view.

Comment: Oh sorry, understand now. Your main view is a view inside de menu controller?

Comment: Right I have a Home screen, and a menu view, and a another view I want to switch to when a cell is clicked. I have 3 classes, home, menu, listings, when I click on a cell, in the menu Class opinion method row selected, I hide the menu, and I need to load new view in place of the home screen, not the menu, as at the moment the menu is getting replaced as I'm calling it in the menu class! Thanks.

Comment: I'm really new to obj c, so sorry for being a bit noobish. I need to call it from another controller, to replace another controller rather than this controller, (self). Can you provide me withe exact code, if you can! Sorry to be such a pain, help much appreciated!

Comment: Dont apologize for be new in obj c, nobody born knowing. Is hard yo provide de exact code cause i dont know the exact distributions of the views. Let me see if i undertand fine. You have 3 controllers (with theris .h. .m and .xib) ? or you have ona view controller with 3 viws, menu, principal view, and other view (what is this view? a header or something) If you have a 3 views together, when you tap on your cell view, you can change the home view, instead using menu to add subview use home yo call it.

Comment: I have 3 controllers, each with h, m and xib. I need to switch home screen view to listings view from the menu class.

Comment: Wooo, i'm a little slow :) can you post some of your code? (even if it is not working)

Comment: Well the only bit relevant it the one I posted in original post, and this is ran durning the didselectrow method in menu class, obviously self switches the menu view to listings view, I need to change home screen view, to listings view.